# Dynamically fetch SharePoint List data using REST in an accordion

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, accordion, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a category-based Question and Answer accordion FAQ (codepen link below).

[Accordion FAQ Codepen](https://codepen.io/test456/pen/abmvwKy)

In my example, the *accordion data* (`categories` on the left panel, `question` & `answers` on the right) is static.

I am trying to get my *accordion data* from a custom SharePoint *List* which has 3 columns - `Category`, `Question`, `Answer`.

I have tried the below code to get the SharePoint List data using REST API for a sample *Employees* List. (Codepen link below).

[SharePoint List Data using REST API](https://codepen.io/test456/pen/WNGQOBQ) **Updated**

**Can anyone help me with the code on how I can fetch my accordion data from my custom SharePoint List.**

***Apologies - I was somehow not able to embed the Codepen snippet here.*

Comment: The second code works well in my environment, did it report any error when you use it?

Comment: No error. It works well. I just want to know how the same code or logic can be used for pulling accordion data from a custom list.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an id to the div which you want to show data from SharePoint List.
Then call the method to get list data when switching cards.

My test code for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://files.krve.io/f/eyespot.css'>-->
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch'
    href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/5.6.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin-top: 30px;
      background-color: #eee;
    }

    .list-group.help-group {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding-left: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .list-group.help-group .faq-list {
      display: block;
      top: auto;
      margin: 0 0 32px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.15);
    }

    .list-group.help-group .faq-list .list-group-item {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 13px 16px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-top-left-radius: 2px;
      border-top-right-radius: 2px;
      color: #616161;
      transition: background-color .2s;
    }

    .list-group.help-group .faq-list .list-group-item i.mdi {
      margin-right: 5px;
      font-size: 18px;
      position: relative;
      top: 2px;
    }

    .list-group.help-group .faq-list .list-group-item:hover {
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
    }

    .list-group.help-group .faq-list .list-group-item.active {
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    }

    .list-group.help-group .faq-list .list-group-item:last-of-type {
      border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
      border-bottom: 0;
    }

    .tab-content.panels-faq {
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
    }

    .panel.panel-help {
      box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.15);
      padding-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 2px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #fff;
      margin: 0 0 16px;
    }

    .panel.panel-help a[href^="#"],
    .panel.panel-help a[href^="#"]:hover,
    .panel.panel-help a[href^="#"]:focus {
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .panel.panel-help .panel-heading {
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      padding: 0 16px;
      line-height: 48px;
      border-top-right-radius: 2px;
      border-top-left-radius: 2px;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    }

    .panel.panel-help .panel-heading h2 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 14px 0 14px;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 20px;
      letter-spacing: 0;
      text-transform: none;
    }

    .panel.panel-help .panel-body {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 2px;
      border-top-right-radius: 0;
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .panel.panel-help .panel-body p {
      margin: 0 0 16px;
    }

    .panel.panel-help .panel-body p:last-of-type {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul class="list-group help-group">
        <div class="faq-list list-group nav nav-tabs">
          <a href="#tab1" class="list-group-item active" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> General Help (Power
            Apps/Automate)</a>
          <a href="#tab2" class="list-group-item" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="mdi mdi-account"></i>
            Environment</a>
          <a href="#tab3" class="list-group-item" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="mdi mdi-account-settings"></i>
            Mobile</a>
          <a href="#tab4" class="list-group-item" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
            Maintainability</a>
          <a href="#tab5" class="list-group-item" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="mdi mdi-cart"></i> Errors</a>
          <!--<a href="#tab6" class="list-group-item" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="mdi mdi-heart"></i> Lorem ipsum</a>
                     <a href="#tab7" class="list-group-item" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i> Dolor sit amet</a>-->
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="tab-content panels-faq">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
          <div class="panel-group" id="help-accordion-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-help">
              <a href="#opret-produkt" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#help-accordion-1">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h2>How do I edit my profile?</h2>
                </div>
              </a>
              <div id="opret-produkt" class="collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus nesciunt ut officiis
                    accusantium quisquam minima praesentium, beatae fugit illo nobis fugiat adipisci quia distinctio
                    repellat culpa saepe, optio aperiam est!</p>
                  <p><strong>Example: </strong>Facere, id excepturi iusto aliquid beatae delectus nemo enim, ad saepe
                    nam et.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-help">
              <a href="#rediger-produkt" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#help-accordion-1">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h2>How do I upload a new profile picture?</h2>
                </div>
              </a>
              <div id="rediger-produkt" class="collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus nesciunt ut officiis
                    accusantium quisquam minima praesentium, beatae fugit illo nobis fugiat adipisci quia distinctio
                    repellat culpa saepe, optio aperiam est!</p>
                  <p><strong>Example: </strong>Facere, id excepturi iusto aliquid beatae delectus nemo enim, ad saepe
                    nam et.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-help">
              <a href="#ret-pris" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#help-accordion-1">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h2>Can I change my phone number?</h2>
                </div>
              </a>
              <div id="ret-pris" class="collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus nesciunt ut officiis
                    accusantium quisquam minima praesentium, beatae fugit illo nobis fugiat adipisci quia distinctio
                    repellat culpa saepe, optio aperiam est!</p>
                  <p><strong>Example: </strong>Facere, id excepturi iusto aliquid beatae delectus nemo enim, ad saepe
                    nam et.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-help">
              <a href="#slet-produkt" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#help-accordion-1">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h2>Where do I change my privacy settings?</h2>
                </div>
              </a>
              <div id="slet-produkt" class="collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus nesciunt ut officiis
                    accusantium quisquam minima praesentium, beatae fugit illo nobis fugiat adipisci quia distinctio
                    repellat culpa saepe, optio aperiam est!</p>
                  <p><strong>Example: </strong>Facere, id excepturi iusto aliquid beatae delectus nemo enim, ad saepe
                    nam et.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-help">
              <a href="#opret-kampagne" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#help-accordion-1">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h2>What is this?</h2>
                </div>
              </a>
              <div id="opret-kampagne" class="collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus nesciunt ut officiis
                    accusantium quisquam minima praesentium, beatae fugit illo nobis fugiat adipisci quia distinctio
                    repellat culpa saepe, optio aperiam est!</p>
                  <p><strong>Example: </strong>Facere, id excepturi iusto aliquid beatae delectus nemo enim, ad saepe
                    nam et.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
          <div class="panel-group" id="help-accordion-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-help">
              <a href="#help-three" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#help-accordion-2">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h2>data from list</h2>
                </div>
              </a>
              <div id="help-three" class="collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body" id="divResults">
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
          <div class="panel-group" id="help-accordion-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-help">
              <a href="#help-three" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#help-accordion-2">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h2>wuhu</h2>
                </div>
              </a>
              <div id="help-three" class="collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>test</p>
                  <p><strong>Example: </strong>Facere, id excepturi iusto aliquid beatae delectus nemo enim, ad saepe
                    nam et.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
          <div class="panel-group" id="help-accordion-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-help">
              <a href="#help-three" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#help-accordion-2">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h2>wuhu</h2>
                </div>
              </a>
              <div id="help-three" class="collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body" >
                  come on,baby
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    // JavaScript Code
    $(function () {
      // Since there's no list-group/tab integration in Bootstrap
      $('.list-group-item').on('click', function (e) {
        var previous = $(this).closest(".list-group").children(".active");
        previous.removeClass('active'); // previous list-item
        getListData();
        $(e.target).addClass('active'); // activated list-item
      });
    });
    function getListData() {
      console.log('22222');
      var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Cities')/items";
      console.log(fullUrl);
      $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: onQuerySucceeded,
        error: onQueryFailed
      });
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
      var listItemInfo = " ";
      $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
        listItemInfo += '<b>Title:</b> ' + value.Title + ' – <b>Industry:</b> ' + value.test + '<br />';
        console.log(listItemInfo);
      });
      $("#divResults").html(listItemInfo);
    }
    function onQueryFailed() {
      alert('Error!');
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Test result:
[image]
Source list:
[image]
**Updated:**

```
function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
      var listItemInfo = " ";
      $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
        listItemInfo += '<b>Title:</b> ' + value.Title + ' – <b>Industry:</b> ' + value.test + '<br />';
        console.log(listItemInfo);
      });
      $("#divResults").html(listItemInfo);
      console.log($(".content").length)
      $(".content").html(listItemInfo);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: have updated the Sharepoint list codepen as per your code. But now, all the questions appear in one div :(

Comment: Here, all values New York, Beijing, others are coming inside one panel-heading div. My requirement is - each div is one question & answer group. ie) in your code 'data from list' is one question (which should fetch from the 'question' column in List), and its answer say 'New York' (which should fetch from the 'Answer' column). And finally all categories - should fetch from the 'Categories' column. Just like how the Question & Answer is in the 'General Help' category.

Comment: I use id selector in the code, so it can only be displayed in one place, you can use other selectors, and add the corresponding element in the code, in the success callback function of the method of obtaining list data according to your need to insert value into the element.

Comment: ok, can you show me how to loop the div for each question & answer, so as to get multiple divs like in "General Help" category.

Comment: I add a new class to the div,and add the same content into the div.You can choose to add different content to difference div according to the content, you can also add different ids to different divs, and then choose to add different divs according to the content, it is not necessary to traverse the div element.

Comment: did you get a chance to check my updated codepen, so I can accept your answer - @Amos_MSFT

Comment: Do you want to add value to some value option?

Comment: Basically, my 'question' will be in the 'h2' tag and the answer should be in the 'panel-body' div. Hope you got it? @Amos_MSFT

Answer (score 0):

You can see in browser all fields of your custom list:

> {you sp-web|site url}/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Employees')

When you call this, you will get a lot of information about list called Employees.

Add at the end of url

> /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Employees')/fields

And there are will be shown xml with fields metadata. So, you can search StaticName for fields ineterested you - this is internal field names, and it's not changes anymore.

When you get all field names, your query will some like this:

> _api/web/lists('667b811c-8764-442f-a33b-c3e7c6b51a04')/items?select=Id,Title,Field1,Field2

Call list by Guid - more stable, because list name can be changed and query will broken.
If some fields is complex data (not string, number, etc), you must write in query

> $expand=Field/Subfield (data)

REST return top 100 elements - this is performance limitation.
So, you must request your data by paging:

> $skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID={last requested Id}&$top=100

More information see on [MSDN about REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom)

If you work in SharePoint Online, I recomend use [pnpjs](https://pnp.github.io/)